# Trying to understand how to iterate over more-dim Arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, matrix

I am trying to learn how to iterate over arrays and therefore made up my own scenarios to practise on.

Let's say my given matrix is a two-dimensional, therefore an two-dim. Array.
mat =[[1,2,300,-400],[0,3,-1,9],[3,4,-5,1]]

Task 1) Return the Array with the highest sum of the values.
Task 2) Given that this Array could produce a nxm matrix, return the value of the row and column for which the sum of the enclosing number is the highest.
To make it easier to understand let us use a different matrix here.
mat= [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]
So it would look like this:

1111

2222

3333

4444

And the result would be [2,1] or [2,2]
since the sum for those numbers (2+2+2+3+3+4+4+4) = 24 would be the highest.

Here are my implementations so far:

Task 1)
I only can solve this with adding a sum function to the class Array.

```
def max_row(mat)
  return mat.max{|a,b| a.sum <=> b.sum }
end

class Array
  def sum
    sum = 0
    self.each(){|x|
      sum += x
    }
    return sum
  end
end
```

I do want to solve it without using an extra method so, but I do not know how to.
my idea so far :

```
def max_row(mat)
  sum_ary = []
mat.each(){|ary|
  sum = 0
  ary.each(){|x|
    sum += x
  }
  sum_ary << [sum]
}
```

I tried find_index on my sum_ary, but as implemented it returns the first value which is not false, therefore I cannot use it to search for the biggest value.

Implementation Task 2):
mat = [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]

```
def max_neighbor_sum(mat)
  sum_result = []
  for  n in 0...mat.size()
    for m in 0...mat.size()
      sum = 0
      for a in (n-1)..(n+1)
        for b in (m-1)..(m+1)
          if m != nil && n !=nil && a>=0 && b>=0 && a<= (mat.size()-1)
#            print "n:#{n} m:#{m} a:#{a} b:#{b} \n"
#            p mat[a][b]
if mat[a][b] !=nil && !(n==a && m==b)
    sum += mat[a][b]
end
  end
end
          end
          sum_result << sum
# p sum_result

    end
  end
  return sum_result
end
```

I calculated all the sums correctly, but have no idea how I get the index for the row and column now.

I hope you can understand where I need some help.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ Your `Array#sum` method might be re-written as simple as `reduce(&:+)`. Try: `[1,2,3,4].reduce &:+`.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out to understand the syntax.

Comment: I am not sure if my @yourname worked, therefore could you please check my latest comment for the answer below?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:

```
arrays.map(&:sum).max
```

Calls sum for each of the arrays, then chooses the biggest of them

Problem 2 can't be solved so easily, but this should work:

```
max_sum = 0
max_index = []

for n in 0...mat.size
  for m in 0...mat.size
    sum = 0
    for a in (n-1)..(n+1)
      for b in (m-1)..(m+1)
        sum += mat[a][b] unless mat[a].nil? || mat[a][b].nil?
      end
    end
    if sum > max_sum
      max_sum = sum
      max_index = [n,m]
    end
  end
end

max_sum # => maximum sum of all neighbours
max_index # => a pair of indexes which have the max sum
```

If you want to keep all of max indexes, just replace it with an array of pairs and push if the `sum` is equal to `max_sum`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help, I will look into this during the weekend.

Comment: I put a def and end in front of your code, then used the method on a given matrix [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]] & used return max_index. at the end. Result : [3,3], so it is not working the way it was intended.

Comment: Okay i found the problem: 
You worte sum = max_sum
It has to be max_sum = sum
then it works :)
No..somehow it is still wrong. But you really helped me solving it!

Comment: Sorry about the typo, glad I helped :)

Comment: Okay I have re-written my sum method so it works for object.
def sum(ary)
  return ary.reduce(:+)
end
@mudasobwa I did not find the & in the result documentation, why did you use it?
So how do I re-write your solution for Task 1? 
I dont know how to adress the current element of the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to task 2 which I came up with thanks to Piotr Kruczek.
Thanks for the kind help!

```
def max_neighbour_sum(mat)
  sum_result = []
  max_sum = 0
  for  n in 0...mat.size()
    for m in 0...mat.size()
      sum = 0
      for a in (n-1)..(n+1)
        for b in (m-1)..(m+1)
          if m != nil && n !=nil && a>=0 && b>=0 && a<= (mat.size()-1)
            #            print "n:#{n} m:#{m} a:#{a} b:#{b} \n"
            #            p mat[a][b]
            if mat[a][b] !=nil && !(n==a && m==b)
              sum += mat[a][b]
            end
          end
        end
      end
      if sum > max_sum
         max_sum = sum
        sum_result = [n,m]
      end
      # p sum_result
    end
  end
  return sum_result
end
```